# MySQL query with enum values

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, reserved-words

I've the following structure in MySQL 5.6.19.

```
CREATE TABLE `metadata` (
`md5` char(32) NOT NULL,
`match` enum('none','md5','similarity') DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And I got an error doing a query like this:

```
select * from metadata where match = 'md5';
```

The error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '= 'md5'' at line 1

There're multiple entries in the table and rows that could match the query. But MySQL refuse to do it. Any idea about the reason?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MATCH` is reserved keyword in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html. You should enclose your field name in backticks to make it work:

```
select * from metadata where `match` = 'md5';
```

Comment: @cyberteo please mark your question as being solved.

Comment: @Begueradj Sure, but the system denies me to do it before 10 minutes after the post of the question :)